# How to find a label by it's innertext in an unordered list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

Ok, here's my problem. I have a select dropdown with different values. If i select one of them, a template is cloned into an unordered list. The thing is, i want to make sure that you cant clone the same element twice.

In the cloned list-elements there is a  which has an inner-text that is the same as the corresponding label of the option in the select dropdown.

Alas i try to find a label in the unordered-list with the same text as the currently selected option in the dropdown. If there is such a label, it should not proceed with the cloning.

Here's my code:

```
$ ->
  $('#add_feature').change ->     //#add_feature is the id of my select option dropdown
    features = $('ul#features')   //features is the unordered list, where i append my 
                                  //cloned list elements

    ...

    selected = $(this).find('option:selected')   //here i find the currently selected
                                                 //option


    //this is where i want to have an if clause or something that compares the
    //inner text of all the labels in the UL to the text of the currently 
    //selected option

    //this is the cloning procedure which should only be called if there is
    //no label found above

    feature = $('#template_feature li').clone()
    features.append(feature)
    $(feature).find('#home_features_attributes_new_type').val(selected.data('type'))
    $(feature).find('#home_features_attributes_new_name').val($(this).val())
    $(feature).find('label[for="home_features_attributes"]').prepend(selected.text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `filter` for exact text matching:

```
var selectedText = selected.text();
var matches = $('option', this).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == selectedText;
 });
if (matches.length == 0){
      // No match!
}
```

If you need case-insensitve either use a constructed regex with the `/i` option, or just make both lowercase:

```
var selectedText = selected.text().toLowerCase();
var matches = $('option', this).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == selectedText;
 });
if (matches.length == 0){
      // No match!
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That didn't seem to do the trick for me. Maybe i converted it wrong from JS to CoffeeScript, although i double checked with a converter.

Comment: If you can post a fiddle with the new code I will look for typos. I wrote that from memory, so not tested live. I could do with seeing the actual HTML too :)